# Issue when using sudo npm -g install create-react-app

Tags: node.js, npm-install

When running sudo npm -g install create-react-app I get the following output:

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'create-react-app@5.0.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security     updates. Please upgrade asap.

changed 67 packages, and audited 68 packages in 24s

5 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

2 high severity vulnerabilities

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details
```

when running npm audit it returns 0 vunerabilities.

also for the node version I have verified I am using version 18.5.0 so I am unsure why it keeps reading it as v12.22.9

I am still rather new to using most of this stuff so any help would be appreciated.

I am just trying to install react.js on my machine.

Comment: Notice that your node version is outdated for what is expected (per the error output. requires node 14+, you have 12.22.9). Further, I don't think it's appropriate to globally install `create-react-app`.

Comment: I see three problems: one: you're installing CRA globally, when it's meant to be run as a one-off with `npx` (unless you're consistently updating the global package); two, you're using `sudo` which you should almost never have to do with npm; and three, you probably have two different versions of Node installed, maybe at different places in your PATH.